# How to get the list of places/landmarks in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, maps, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to implement a search functionality where user tries to search for  a area/landmark in a city, we should populate the list below. Is there any API to get list of areas/landmarks of a city.

Comment: Have you seen this : http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit ? It's a little out of date but has the main principles about using the places API

Comment: Adding onto what @Ollie said, here's the Google Places API docs: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/